# How to make Lombok's EqualsAndHashCode work with BigDecimal

Tags: java, equals, hashcode, bigdecimal, lombok

I have exactly the problem described [here](http://tech.transferwise.com/fun-with-bigdecimal/). This is, being `BigDecimal`'s equals being broken as it is, having such a field in a class prevents using `@EqualsAndHashCode`. The only solution I came up with is to `exclude` such fields, but of course this is not optimal.

Is there any solution? Any way of injecting my own comparator for a field/type?

Comment: Always call `stripTrailingZeroes` before storing your `BigDecimal` in the field?

Comment: Uf, I'd prefer not to have to clutter the code just for comparisons.

Comment: You can also always set the scale for BigDecimal. See the example: https://repl.it/CFag/0

Comment: @RaphaelAmoedo Same problem that with Andy's suggestion.

Comment: Then probably you have to override Equals by yourself...

Comment: The setScale can be used too on getter (which you'd have to write it)... Then, probably the EqualsAndHashCode, according to Lombok's documentation will work.

Comment: Could you store the BigDecimal as a String and convert the String to a BigDecimal in the getter and the setter ?

Comment: Reported as [#1260](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1260), and closed with [a workaround](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1260#issuecomment-268114093).

Comment: I fail to see how `BigDecimal`s `equal()` is broken. You could argue Strings are broken in Java since `!"Foo".equals("foo")`

Comment: The link is dead as of now

Answer (score 6):

I faced the same issue recently.

Basically, you see this behavior:

```
BigDecimal x = new BigDecimal("2");
BigDecimal y = new BigDecimal("2.00");
System.out.println(x.equals(y));                              // False
System.out.println(x.compareTo(y) == 0 ? "true": "false");    // True
```

There's no a good solution that will work out of the box, but you may redefine BigDecimal field value being used in hashCode & equals:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode
class Test Class {

  @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
  private BigDecimal amount;
  ...

  @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
  private BigDecimal getAmountForEquals() {
    return ofNullable(amount).map(BigDecimal::stripTrailingZeros).orElse(null);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it’s not Lombok’s fault, since it is quite unclear how to compare `BigDecimal` in general. Anyway, the following example code presents a solution:

```
import lombok.AccessLevel;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class WithBigDecimals {

    private int i;

    private String s;

    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private BigDecimal d;

    @Getter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    @ToString.Exclude
    private final BigDecimalComparer _bdc = new BigDecimalComparer();

    private class BigDecimalComparer {
        public WithBigDecimals getOuter() {
            return WithBigDecimals.this;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (!(obj instanceof BigDecimalComparer))
                return false;
            BigDecimalComparer other = (BigDecimalComparer) obj;
            double epsilon = d.doubleValue() / 1000d;
            return d.doubleValue() - epsilon < other.getOuter().d.doubleValue() &&
                    other.getOuter().d.doubleValue() < d.doubleValue() + epsilon;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var a = new WithBigDecimals(42, "2.4", new BigDecimal("2.4"));
        var b = new WithBigDecimals(42, "2.4", new BigDecimal("2.40"));
        var c = new WithBigDecimals(42, "2.4", new BigDecimal(2.4));

        System.out.printf("%s == %s  ??  %b%n", a, b, a.equals(b));
        System.out.printf("%s == %s  ??  %b%n", b, c, b.equals(c));
        System.out.printf("%s == %s  ??  %b%n", a, c, a.equals(c));
    }

}
```

As you can see, the `BigDecimal` is exluded from `@EqualsAndHashCode`. To re-inject it, I have created another field which is only privately accessed. It is used in the auto-generated `equals()` method and can provide comparisons at will. I used a simple version of almost-equality here.

Comment: Warning: coding ```equals``` as *equal within some value of epsilon* can result in a result that says *a* equals *b* and *b* equals *c* but that *a* does not equal *c*.

Comment: Absolutely. However, the OP claims that `equals()` for `BigDecimal` is broken, and I couldn’t come up with a any allegedly non-broken implementation.

Comment: You don't need to convert `BigDecimals` to `doubles` to compare them. To avoid any issue with equal values but different scales you must use `BigDecimal.compare()`, which returns 0 when they represent the same value.

Answer (score 0):

The answers already provided are steps in the right direction. I didn't want to pull away from my double and I certainly didn't want to have to rewrite the equals and hash for the other 15 metrics of my class. So I have something similar (hopefully it can help others):

```
/**
 * Calculated percentage 
 */
@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
private Double percentage;

/**
 * @return percentage rounded to 5 digits specifically for equals comparison sot
 */
@EqualsAndHashCode.Include
private Double percentageForEquals() {
    return Math.round(percentage * 1e5) / 1e5;
}
```