# Generate Lombok equals method with ignorecase

Tags: java, lombok

Is is possible to annotate a `String` field so Lombok generates an equals method which ignores the character case of the `String` value.

That is, generate something like this:

```
public class Foo {
    private String bar;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Foo foo = (Foo) o;

        return bar != null ? StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(bar, foo.bar) : foo.bar == null;
    }    
}
```

Comment: related: stackoverflow.com/q/36625347/3014199

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, but don't do it.

Lombok is not a tool for customization. It is an instrument to omit boilerplate code.

`@EqualsAndHashCode` produce code that call getters for each field to compare.
To solve the problem implement getter:

```
public getBar() {
    return bar != null ? bar.toLowerCase() : null;
}
```

Comparison will be in lowercase. After this getter will be *broken*.

Comment: please elaborate on "After this getter will be broken"

Comment: I'm using apache commons-lang `EqualsBuilder` and `HashCodeBuilder` to implement this behavior. P.s. "getter will be broken" means that the getter is not a getter anymore, as it transforms the `bar` field instead of simply returning it.

Comment: @asgs I guess the author means that the `lombok` will not generate the getter for `bar` field, since the getter for field is already present, and in equals/hashcode methods it will just use this custom method, that lowercasess the `bar` field value.

Comment: thank you for the clarification, JulienKronegg and mihail2048

Answer (score 4):

You can exclude fields from equals and include custom functions:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode
class Foo {

    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private String bar;

    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private String normalizedBar() {
        return bar != null ? bar.toLowerCase() : null;
    }
}
```

This question deals with a similar issue: [How to make Lombok's EqualsAndHashCode work with BigDecimal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36625347/3014199)
More discussion here: https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/1260#issuecomment-268114093